# execute simple task when time expires (PIC18 C)

Tags: c, scheduled-tasks, pic

I want to set a bit (an output of the PIC18 MCU), and reset it "automatically" when a given amount of time expires. (or being able to execute a method when the time expires)

In higher level programming, you can use classes like TimerTask in Java to do that, but now I need to do this in ANSI C code...

I configured TMR4 to increment a timestamp value every 10ms.

So i call in my code

```
void resetBit(int byte, int bitnr, int time);
```

How do I keep track of the code that needs to be executed? When the TMR4 interrupt is fired, the timestamp should be compared and if needed execute the pending methods. Whats the best way to save the function calls and there timestamps in memory?

Comment: When the interrupt is triggered, increment a counter variable. When the counter has reached the expected value, reset it and call your function. There is nothing called "ANSI C" since the year 1990... we use ISO/IEC C since then. Americans might nationally call it 
INCITS/ISO/IEC, but nobody outside the US cares.

Comment: I can save a pointer to a function that needs to be executed after x ms. How do i keep the arguments for that function call? I think i need some kind of list structure with pointers to functions to execute, their arguments and the time to expire before executing the function?

Comment: Usually you'd make an "ADT" driver around the timer which keeps track of all callback functions. (There's some examples posted on SO somewhere, but I can't find them.)

Comment: do you have any more information about hat ADT driver? I entered it in the search box but i did not find useful information?

Comment: ADT means abstract data type and is a way to design programs. In this context it means that you create some code that can take function pointers of a given format, store them internally (usually in a linked list) and then call them when the timer elapses, without knowing anything about what those functions do or where they are located.